# Eclipse: find color setting used at specific position

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse often font and background colors are not as readable as you want, especially when using a dark theme. In this case you need to test which color to change in the preferences, and see if this changes the correct color in the editor. Or search forums.

Is there a way to e.g. highlight text and get information, which color name in the settings determines the color of the font and background? Maybe some neat plugin I missed?

Comment: For own customizations the [Jeeeyul's Eclipse Themes](https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes) is quite good. You might have also a look at the [Eclipse Spectrum Dark Theme](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-spectrum-dark-theme) and the [Eclipse Color Theme](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme). But keep in mind that a dark theme is always less ergonomic than a light theme since the human eye needs more light to work best.

Comment: Thank you for the links, but more theme customizations would mean more colors which might or might not apply at a certain position. In my humble opinion this would aggravate the problem. And I have worked some years with a light theme, it caused a lot of stress on my eyes. Going dark was a good decision. Also if you look at the [high contrast of a dark theme](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/february/images/darkest-dark.png) you see that the eyes need less focus to differentiate the colors.